Docker + Next Auth OAuth hangs forever
After running my website on Vercel, I want to transition to a custom server setup on a dedicated server. My code works perfectly without docker.
I am using Next Auth, Drizzle, and Docker. The sign-in button works, then you are redirected to Google where you fill in your info, but it is never able to redirect back to my website--it just hangs forever. I've even tried setting up console.log statements in the signIn callback, but nothing is logged. The only thing I get in the console is a 302 response code once I manually close the page, stopping the loading.
Below is a snippet of my package.json, docker-compose.yaml, and auth.js.
package.json
"@auth/drizzle-adapter": "^1.1.0",
"drizzle-kit": "^0.21.2",
"drizzle-orm": "^0.30.10",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
"next": "^14.2.3"

docker-compose.yaml
services:
    app:
        image: node:22.2
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c 'npm i && npm run dev'
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:3000:3000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - TURBOPACK=1
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
            - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
        env_file:
            - .env
        restart: unless-stopped
    db:
        image: postgres:16.3
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
        volumes:
            - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        env_file:
            - .env
        restart: unless-stopped

auth.js
const scopes = ['userinfo.profile', 'userinfo.email']
    .map(scope => `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/${scope}`)
    .join(' ')

export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    auth
} = NextAuth({
    adapter: DrizzleAdapter(db, {
        usersTable: users,
        accountsTable: accounts,
        sessionsTable: sessions,
        verificationTokensTable: verificationTokens
    }) as Adapter,
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
            authorization: {
                params: { scope: scopes }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        signIn: async ({ user }) => {
            console.log('signIn', user)

            if (!('customerId' in user)) {
                // Just created account

                console.log('no customer id')

                const { id: customerId } = await stripe.customers.create({
                    metadata: { userId: user.id! },
                    name: user.name!,
                    email: user.email!
                })

                console.log('created customer id', customerId)

                ;(user as any).customerId = customerId
            }

            return true
        },
        session: async ({ session, user }) => {
            if (session.user)
                Object.assign(
                    session.user,
                    pick(
                        user,
                        'id',
                        'phone',
                        'allowNotifications',
                        'customerId'
                    )
                )

            return session
        }
    },
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: `${!DEV ? '__Secure-' : ''}authjs.session-token`,
            options: {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                path: '/',
                domain: !DEV
                    ? new URL(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ORIGIN!).hostname
                    : undefined,
                secure: !DEV
            }
        }
    },
    trustHost: true
})

On a side note, after moving to Docker, my google fonts started throwing this error:
Error while requesting resource
There was an issue establishing a connection while requesting https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700;900&display=swap.

But the auth is a more pressing issue.
